# c++ passing derived class object to global function where base class object is expected

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, constructor, argument-passing

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    int b;
    base() { b = 0; }
    void func1() {}
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    int d;
    derived() { d = 9; }
};

void func(base* bobj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, bobj++)
        cout << bobj->b;
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    base bobj[5];
    func(bobj);
    derived dobj[5];
    func(dobj);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000
09090
```

Here when I pass derived object to func() which is expecting base pointer, I am getting output as 09090, but I did not understand why..
Can someone please explain the second output why it is printing 09090..??

Answer (score 1):

Treating an array of derived-class objects as an array of base-class objects gives undefined behaviour.

Specifically, `bobj++` will increment the pointer by the size of `base`, not the size of `derived`, leaving it pointing to somewhere in the middle of an object, not to the next object. In your case, it happens to point to the `d` member of the first object, which gets misinterpreted as the `b` member of the second object, hence the unexpected `9` in the output. But, being undefined, you can't rely on that behaviour; in principle, anything could happen.

Comment: thanks a lot for your clear explanation. But still I have a doubt when we say "bobj->b" will it not search for value "b" at the same memory location..?? how come just the value at that memory location get printed without checking whether it is "b" or "d" ..??

Comment: @user3440508: Yes, it looks for `b` at the memory location it would be at if `bobj` pointed to a valid `base` object. But since it doesn't point to a valid object (since it was adjusted by the wrong amount), it finds something else instead. Nothing is "checked"; the program assumes the pointer is valid, and fails (giving undefined behaviour) if it isn't.